# Position in Dataframe with repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, position, rank

I am trying to implement a game. 
For this, the players are being ranked based on values they enter.
The game is dynamical and the values they enter are being added up after every round. Then the game compares again who is the

first one, who is the second one etc. 
I also want to give them their current position. However, this is not easy if 2 Players enter the same values:(Each position in the list below is a player)

```
E.g.: entered values round 1 = [2, 4, 5, 4]
Rank [1, 2, 3, 2], 
Position [1, 2, 4, 2]
```

In the end, I want to return the current position to the players, for example player 1: Current position is 1/4
Player 3: Current position is 4/4

(Note that the ranks and positions can change from round to round. That's the reason why a variable like current_position would be good)

I created the Dataframe for the players and the values already and was able to assign a rank by using `df['Rank'] = df['values'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int).`

I could get the position by using `df[Position] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int)`

However, this adds a column to the dataframe. I need to assign each current position to the respective player. They should not see the Positions of the other players. 
The example below is static. I think if the static solution works, it is quite easy to transfer it to a dynamic solution

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

names = ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Kyle']
values = [2, 4, 5, 4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'Values': values})
columns = ["Name", "Values"]

df['Rank'] = df['Values'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
```

[image: DataFrame]

Comment: What do you mean by "They should not see the Positions of the other players"? They will see what you will show them, no matter what the variables in python are. Just show each player his own data with `df[df['Name'] == player_name]`.

Comment: There are different groups in this game. Group A sees the Dataframe with Name, Value, Rank, Group B should only see something like this: "You'r current position is 3/4"

Comment: So if it's their turn, they would see `df[df['Name'] == player_name]`, and if not they would see `print(" ".join(["Your current position is", str(df.loc[df['Name'] == player_name, 'Rank']), "of", str(len(df))])`

Comment: Just to be sure, you say I should create a new dataframe that only shows the row of the respective player  by df[df['Name'] == player_name]. Then The other code shows assesses the value in cell rank, right? Do you know how to get the position? Because there is a slight difference between rank and position if the players enter the same values

Comment: There is no reason to create another dataframe. Add a column of `position` to this dataframe. And if you don't want to use `rank` but only `position`, then don't have a column of `rank`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally am a beginner of coding so I am quite confused. I tried: **df['Position'] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int).** Then **print(" ".join(["Your current position is", str(df.loc[df['Name'] == "Tom", 'Position']), "of", str(len(df))])**. However, I get an error message in Jupyter Notebook "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing".What went wrong?

Comment: Sorry, add another `)` to the end of the `print` line

Comment: Thank you so much @Aryerez! It is working but when I run it in Jupyter Notebook, it says **Your current position is 1    2
Name: Position, dtype: int32 of 4**  as output. Do you know how to get rid of the part from 2 to int32?

Comment: Apparently it should be: `str(df.loc[df['A'] == "man too", 'A'].iloc[0])`. This is what happens when one writes code without testing :)

Comment: hi, it's been quite a long time since I've asked the last time but I still get an error message when using iloc.
**df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, ''Values': values})
                    df['Rank'] = df['Values'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
                    df['Position'] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int)
                    df.set_index('Rank', inplace=True)**

Comment: **df.sort_values(by="Values", ascending=False)
                    df.sort_values(by="Rank", ascending=False)
                    end_position = str(df.loc[df['Name'] == self.player, 'Position'].iloc[0])**

Comment: The error message says it is an Index Error: "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" in the last line, so here **end_position = str(df.loc[df['Name'] == self.player, 'Position'].iloc[0])**